# How to extract Domain from DNS data in hive

Tags: regex, hive

How to extract the domain name from the DNS data.

The example I want to extract domain from:

```
www.google.com
```

The result should be `google`.

I am using hive to fetch the data from Hadoop and using regular extract function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
   select case when size(site_name_splitted )=3 then site_name_splitted[1]
               when size(site_name_splitted )=2 then site_name_splitted[0]
             end as domain
      from
    (
        select split(col,'\\.') as site_name_splitted from mytable
    )s
```